# Bind Rows For Loop in R Randomly Stops Working?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, rbind

I am scraping NBA play by play data using the play_by_play function in the nbastatR package. The problem is this function only collects data for 1 game ID at a time, and there are 1230 game IDs in a complete season. When I enter more than 15 game ID's in the play_by_play function, R just keeps loading and showing the wheel of death forever.

I tried to get around this by making a for loop which binds each game id to one cumulative dataframe. However, I run into the same error where R will endlessly load around the 16'th game- very peculiar. I could clean the data in the loop and try that out (I do not need all play by play data, just every shot from the season), but does anyone know why this is happening and how/if I could get around this?

Thanks

```
full<- play_by_play(game_ids = 21400001, nest_data = F, return_message = T)
for(i in 21400002:21400040){
        data <- play_by_play(game_ids = c(i), nest_data = F, return_message = F)
        full <- bind_rows(full,data)
        cat(i)
}
```

This code will stop working at around the the 16th game ID. I tried using bind_rows from dplyr but that did not help at all.

Comment: I suspect it's a lazy evaluation problem.  Try changing the `for` loop to an `lapply` or similar.

Comment: Also, for efficiency, move the `bind_rows` outside the loop.  This is natural when using `lapply`.

Comment: Okay thanks Ill give that a shot.

Comment: @Limey, sorry I suck with lapply I have no clue what I am doing. Are you saying make a list storing each gameID of play_by_play and then lapply(list, bind_rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [untested code as I don't have your data]:

```
full <- lapply(
          21400001:21400040,
          function(i) {
            play_by_play(game_ids = c(i), nest_data = F, return_message = F)
          }
        ) %>%
        bind_rows()
```

You can get more information on lazy evaluation [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).

Comment: This is much much faster.

Comment: That’s the effect of moving bind_rows out of the loop.